# Check if FontFamily is TrueType

Tags: c#, fonts, c++-cli, truetype

Is it possible to determine whether a certain font family is a TrueType-font using C#, C++/CLI or by P/Invoking the WinAPI?

In the end I would like to have some result like this

```
bool result1 = CheckIfIsTrueType(new FontFamily("Consolas")); //returns true
bool result2 = CheckIfIsTrueType(new FontFamily("Arial")); // returns true
bool result3 = CheckIfIsTrueType(new FontFamily("PseudoSaudi")); // returns false
bool result4 = CheckIfIsTrueType(new FontFamily("Ubuntu")); // returns true
bool result5 = CheckIfIsTrueType(new FontFamily("Purista")); // returns false
```

Of course the results are dependant of the target Operating System and its fonts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has the overhead of handling an exception, but the [`FontFamily` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ext31w1(v=vs.110).aspx) throws an `ArgumentException` if the supplied font is not TrueType:

```
public bool CheckIfIsTrueType(string font)
{
    try
    {
        var ff = new FontFamily(font)
    }
    catch(ArgumentException ae)
    {
        // this is also thrown if a font is not found
        if(ae.Message.Contains("TrueType"))
            return false;        

        throw;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Digging into the FontFamily constructor, it calls the external GDIPlus function `GdipCreateFontFamilyFromName`:

```
[DllImport("Gdiplus", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CharSet=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode)] // 3 = Unicode
internal static extern int GdipCreateFontFamilyFromName(string name, HandleRef fontCollection, out IntPtr FontFamily);
```

which return a code of `16` if the font is not a true type font.  So you can bypass the overhead of an exception:

```
public bool CheckIfIsTrueType(string name)
{
    IntPtr fontfamily = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr nativeFontCollection = IntPtr.Zero ;

    int status = GdipCreateFontFamilyFromName(name, new HandleRef(null, nativeFontCollection), out fontfamily);

    if(status != 0)
        if(status == 16)  // not true type font)
            return false;
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("GDI Error occurred creating Font");

    return true;
}
```

Obviously you might want to use an enum of constants for the codes, which can be found [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/Gdiplus.cs,bef5947ab71d4d1f), and throw a better exception

Answer (score 1):

If the target Operating System is Windows 10 you would not get an exception executing D Stanley's C# sample code. The exception is only thrown on windows 7. OTF fonts with Adobe CFF outlines are supported by GDI+ on windows 8 and Windows 10.  see the table at the bottom of this link -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdiplus/-gdiplus-creating-a-private-font-collection-use